# Add Bot to MS Teams private channels

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there any workaround to be able to create, update and delete conversation on private channels using code?

Comment: HI @chiaDev, Could you please go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=dotnet) for your reference. And Let us know if your issue get resolved

Comment: Hi @Ravindra-MSFT, thanks, I am aware of the update/delete of bot messages. But I cant seem to be able to get the bot to send a message on **private** channels in the first place. I am wondering if there is any workaround to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bots are not supported in private channels yet. Currently, there is no workaround.

Comment: Still not supported ?

Comment: @RamenTurismo - This is still not supported. You can [configure RSS Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/whats-new#to-configure-rss-feed) to get updates on Microsoft Teams Platform changes.